# Typescript reads var as empty array in some functions, but not in others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I'm working on a React app functional component to allow users to draw a google maps route by selecting points on the map and having google maps draw the in between.

The markers that the user selects are being stored in a state variable to be passed into the backend later, and the same points are being saved in a var in the top of this functional component.

```
var markers = []
```

is declared at the top of the function. When the user clicks a point on the map, the coordinate value is added to the `markers` array. There is another function `drawRoute` that reads this array and draws the points to the map.

There are buttons on the side of the map that run `undo` and `clear` functions that function as they should on the state values for these markers, but leaves the `markers` array completely unchanged, as the `drawRoute` function acts as if there was no change to this array.

I put in some `console.log(markers)` in different parts of this component, and it seems to return an empty array anywhere I put it, except in the `drawRoute` function.

Am I just writing bad react/typescript code? Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, {useState,useRef,useEffect} from 'react';
import RouteInput from './routeInput';
import './Map.scss'


type GoogleLatLng = google.maps.LatLng;
type GoogleMap = google.maps.Map;

const zoomNumber = 11;
    
const AddRouteMap: React.FC<any> = ({defaultCenter}) => {
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
const [map, setMap] = useState<GoogleMap>();
const [markerState,setMarkerState] = useState([])
const [directionsService, setDirectionsService] = useState<any>()
const [directionsDisplay, setDirectionsDisplay] = useState<any>()
const [mapMode, setMapMode] = useState(true)
const [routeLength,setRouteLength] = useState(0)


//Keep track of markers drawn
var markers = []
var firstMarker


//Use effect function to initialize the map
const startMap = ():void => {
    if (!map) {
        defaultMapStart();
    }
}
useEffect(startMap, [map])

//Wrapper function to initialize map
const defaultMapStart = ():void => {
    const defaultAddress = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultCenter.lat, defaultCenter.lng)
    initMap(zoomNumber,defaultAddress)
}

//Use effect fucntion to initialize directions service
const initDirectionsService = () => {
    if (!directionsService)
    {
        setDirectionsService(
            new google.maps.DirectionsService()
        )
    }
}
useEffect(initDirectionsService,[directionsService])

//Use effect fucntion to initialize directions renderer
const initDirectionsDisplay = () => {
    if (!directionsDisplay)
    {
        setDirectionsDisplay(
            new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map
            })
        )
    }
}
useEffect(initDirectionsDisplay,[directionsDisplay])

// Establish an event listener for each marker click
const initEventListener = () => {
    if (map) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            addMarker(e.latLng)
        })
    }
}
useEffect(initEventListener,[map])

// Function to add marker to the map/marker array
const addMarker = (coordinant: GoogleLatLng) => {
    setMarkerState(markerState=>[...markerState,coordinant])
    markers = [...markers,coordinant]


    drawRoute()
}

// Effect used to draw the markers by 
// mapping over the marker array and
// setting the marker's map to map
const drawRoute = () => {
    console.log("markers:")
    console.log(markers)
    if (!map)
        return;
    directionsDisplay.setMap(null)
    directionsDisplay.setOptions({
        suppressMarkers: false,
        preserveViewport: true
    })
    // If the first marker exists and there are no markers
    if (markers.length === 0 && firstMarker)
    {
        firstMarker.setMap(null)
    }
    // If there's one marker
    if (markers.length === 1)
    {
        // If firstMarker hasn't been initialized, do that now
        if (!firstMarker)
        {
            firstMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markers[0],
                map: map
            })
        }
        //Draw only firstMarker 
        else
        {
            firstMarker.setPosition(markers[0])
            firstMarker.setMap(map)
        }
    }
    // Draw route if there's more than 1 marker
    else if (markers.length >= 2) {
        firstMarker.setMap(null)

        // Initialize waypoint list for all but first and last marker
        var waypnts = []
        for (var i = 1; i < markers.length - 1; i++) {
            console.log(markers[i])
            waypnts.push({
                location: markers[i],
                stopover: false
            })
        }

        // Generate and draw route
        directionsService.route({
            origin: markers[0],
            destination: markers[markers.length-1],
            waypoints: waypnts,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status){
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK && map) {
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map)
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
            } else {
                if (waypnts.length > 23)
                    window.alert("Waypoint limit reached")
                else
                    window.alert("Directions request failed")
                markers.pop()
                drawRoute()
            }
            //calculate length
            var length = 0
            var leg
            response.routes[0].legs.forEach(leg => {
                length = length + leg.distance.value
                console.log("leg",leg.distance.value)
            })
            setRouteLength(()=>length*0.000621371)
        })
    }
}
//useEffect(drawRoute,[markerState])

const removeOneMarker = () => {
    console.log("Removed Marker Set")
    console.log(markers)
}

const undo = () => {
    removeOneMarker()
    setMarkerState((markerState)=>markerState.slice(0,-2))
    drawRoute()
}

const clear = () => {
    markers = []
    setMarkerState(() => [])
    drawRoute()
}

const switchView = () => {
    if (!mapMode)
        drawRoute()
    setMapMode(!mapMode)
}



//actual function that starts the map
const initMap = (zoomLevel: number, address: GoogleLatLng): void => {
    if (ref.current) {
            setMap( new google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
                zoom: zoomLevel,
                center: address,
                zoomControl: true,
            }))
    }
}

return(
    
    <div className="map-container" >
        {mapMode ? 
        <>
            <div ref={ref} className="map-container__map"></div>
            <button onClick={undo}>Undo</button>
            <button onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
            <button onClick={switchView}>Continue</button>
        </>
        : <>
            <RouteInput markers={markerState} routeLength={routeLength} />
            {/*
            <button onClick={switchView}>Go Back</button>
            */}
          </>

        }
    </div>
)
};

export default AddRouteMap
```

Comment: Probably there's something you misunderstood about React's state management, but without you posting your code, it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: added the code! @ChrisFarmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `markerState` only and not `var markers = []`.

---

Here's what's happening:

1. Your component renders. This means the `AddRouteMap` function is executed.
2. 

```
const [markerState,setMarkerState] = useState([])
```

This line creates marker state and allows the values to persist between renders. This is good.

3.

```
var markers = []
```

This line local variable is created and assigned a value of an empty array. This is bad because every time your component renders, it will be assigned a new and empty array.

---

Later, `addMarker` is called. Then the following happens:

1.

```
setMarkerState(markerState=>[...markerState,coordinant])
```

The new coordinate is added to `markerState`. This is good and exactly what you should do. Since your are calling a state setter function with a new value, React knows that it needs to re-render. This happens asynchronously, a few milliseconds later. So for now your synchronous code continues to run.

2.

```
markers = [...markers,coordinant]
```

Then you *also* update the local variable `markers` with the same new coordinate.

3.

```
drawRoute()
```

You call `drawRoute`, which uses the local variable `markers` that you just updated.

4. After all that, react re-renders. (go to step one in the first list) This means that a new local variable is created by `var markers = []` and assigned an empty array.

---

Your mistake is that you are not using state properly. Delete `var markers = []` entirely and instead just use `markerState` in its place. That will persist the list of markers between renders because of `useState`.

---

I'm not 100% how the libraries you are using work, but you may also need to call `drawRoute()` from an effect. That should look like:

```
useEffect(() => [
  drawRoute()
})
```

`useEffect` will run after the first render, or after any render in which an item in its dependency array has changed. If you call it with no dependencies, then it will execute after every render.

So in this case, if you update `markerState`, then react renders, then the effect is triggered, and it calls draw route on your freshly re-rendered items. This ensures that you always call `drawRoute` after your render.

Comment: I should have mentioned this above. When the map is relying solely on the markerState array, nothing gets drawn or saved into the backend. Replacing all instances of markers with markerState makes it even less functional :(

Comment: This explanation definitely makes things add up a bit more, but if it was re-rendering the markers array to [], why do all of the previous markers stored in the marker array show up on the map instead of becoming completely erased?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see the bit at the end about `useEffect`